# SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY ) AS - When Duplicates Exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, duplicates, window-functions

I have an issue with using SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY) where I have duplicate records.  I can remove the duplicates using DISTINCT but the SUM still performs over all duplicate records.

For instance my data is:

```
--------------------------------------
|ref    |CODES  |VALUE  |SUM         |
--------------------------------------
|101    |CODE1  |20     |150         |
|101    |CODE2  |30     |150         |
|101    |CODE1  |20     |150         |
|101    |CODE2  |30     |150         |
|101    |CODE1  |20     |150         |
|101    |CODE2  |30     |150         |
```

With DISTINCT applied it becomes:

```
--------------------------------------
|ref    |CODES  |VALUE  |SUM         |
--------------------------------------
|101    |CODE1  |20     |150         |
|101    |CODE2  |30     |150         |
```

So the issue is I would hope the SUM column to be 50.

The SUM code is:

```
SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY ref) AS Total
```

I would like to see:

```
--------------------------------------
|ref    |CODES  |VALUE  |SUM         |
--------------------------------------
|101    |CODE1  |20     |50          |
|101    |CODE2  |30     |50          |
```

Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect. Do you want 2 records in the result set, or 6?

Comment: To prevent misnderstandigs, do you use Microsoft sql server as DMBS? Please add the appropiate tag of your rdmbs.

Comment: Would it not make far more sense to remove the duplicates in your table first - rather than compensate in every query that uses the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first `select distinct` in a subquery, then do the window sum:

```
select ref, codes, value, sum(value) over(partition by ref) total
from (select distinct ref, codes, value from mytable) t
```

This would produce a resultset with 2 records and a `total` of `50`.

Comment: Hi, I adapted this a bit to give me what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use group by :

```
select ref, codes, value, sum(value) over(partition by ref) total_sum
from test
group by ref, codes, value;
```

If it is not good for your case scenario please do explain why.
In this example the table name is called `test`.
[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c2dec205aa59f17697a02f920a39f38f)